# how do i integrate joomla jevent email notification?

Tags: email, joomla, notifications

For the joomla 1.5 event module, I used jevent. If any event created, then admin will be notified by email. How can i integrate email notification?

See the link: http://www.srajib.info/s2l/

Comment: Have you done any research on this? Have you contacted the developer of JEvents?

Answer (score 0):

The default installation of JEvents does not include new event notifications but this can be added via a Silver Membership add-on:

http://www.jevents.net/products/new-a-changed-event-nofications

Comment: Is there any free membership to get it?

Comment: No, I don't think so, but JEvents is one of the very few event management extensions to offer this feature at all and a Silver membership only costs about $60.

Answer (score 0):

You could try integrate jEvents with popfeed. Popfeed is a content plugin that works by allowing site visitors to give feedback on joomla articles. With a slight tweaking of the popfeed.php files and the helper.php files you could make it work with jEvents